# Creating an ArrayList of generic Queues that hold objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create a variable amount of generic Queues that hold objects Customer. I was told I couldn't make a simple array and needed to use an ArrayList but I am having an error with my code.

```
ArrayList<MyQueue<Customer>> checkOut = new ArrayList<MyQueue<Customer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < n + k; i++)
     checkOut.add(MyQueue<Customer>);//error "expression expected after ">""
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Must be ``new MyQueue<Customer>()`` in ``add(...)``.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new instance of `MyQueue<Customer>` in the List. Thus you need to instantiate it using the `new` keyword, and the constructor call with the `()`.

```
checkOut.add(new MyQueue<Customer>());
```

Comment: When I use that I get "Syntax error on token ">", expression expected after this token.

Comment: Even after doing the changes?! Do you have a parameterized constructor in your `MyQueue` class? If so, is there a default constructor as well?

Comment: The only constructor in MyQueue is

     public MyQueue()